# Placing an embedded google map marker with Selenium

Tags: google-maps, selenium, google-maps-markers

I have an asp.net website which as part of a wizard uses an embedded google map to select a location by clicking on the map to place a marker. How do I automate this with Selenium?

In particular I've tried:

- ClickAt
- DoubleClickAt
- MouseDownAt
- MouseUpAt

In all cases passing the map div id as the locator and "100,100" as the coordinate.

I don't care where on the map the marker is placed, as long as I can place that marker.

Answer (score 1):

The command:

```
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//div[@id='gmap']/div/div[1]</td>
    <td>(400,300)</td>
</tr>
```

works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Google have "Open Sourced" all their Selenium test scripts for google maps. I'm pretty sure you can find a lot of code to reuse from their scripts.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/wiki/SeleniumTests